# Database field manipulation

Tags: ms-access

I've recieved a database, it is very complex so it's hard to get my head around it. I offered I would clean it up for the owner but looking at the mass of relationships i'd probably change something for the worse. However there is one problem i wish to fix for them, there's a field named LoanStatus the properties are; 
-Text
-ComboBox
-RowSource: "Current";"Returned";"Overdue"

The problem I'm having is whenever you loan out an item, you fill in the row with the asset number and the system will return a due date for you in that row but the problem is, you're able to loan out the same item an infinite amount of times in different tables (to different people), i want to have the LoanStatus field say "AlreadyLoaned" whenever you try to loan it out when it has already been loaned. Again I just got a headache by writing this but i hope you guys will understand it. Thank you for your time!

Im using MS Access 2007

Answer (score 1):

By the principles of Data Normalization, you shouldn't store any values that you can compute from other values in the database. As such, instead of having an "Already Loaned" value, it should be part of a query that grabs values from the database, to check if the book has been loaned out.

It'd be something like:

```
Select Book.id as Name, count(Loan.id) as LoanedCount
from Book
left outer join Loan on Book.id = Loan.bookid
group by Book.id
```

What this does is return every book, alongside a count of every loan it has. The left outer join means you get one row for each book/loan combination, as well as a row of book/no loan if there are no loans for that book. Then, you group all rows that have the same book together, count how many non-null loan ids it has and return that value.

Comment: Thanks guys the select query helped

Answer (score 0):

If you have administrative access to the normalized database you would add a value of "Occupado" for LoanStatus in the appropriate table. Otherwise, some more information about the schema of the ms access database table from which you are retrieving the values would be informative. Besides having to add the new value to the database you'll most likely have to add some rule to the "check out" process.